# MySQL Front 4.1 if statement

Tags: mysql, if-statement

everyone!
How I can write in my sql front 4.1 next logic:

```
  if @partID is null then 
  insert into partid_to_productid (value1, value2)
```

Comment: Should I use if not exists function or there is better solution?

Comment: Is it not sorking with `is null`? To my knowledge `is null` should do alright

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it like

```
if @partID is null then 
insert into partid_to_productid(col1,col2) values(value1, value2);
end if;
```